# jquery addclass and hasclass with animate.css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am trying to use addclass and hasclass to add animate.css animation to the division class.

```
<section class="main active">
 ...
</section>
<section class="aboutus">
    <h1>About Us</h1>
    <p class="aboutus-text">
    Text
    </p>
</section>
```

The above is the HTML code that I am trying to animate.

So when scrolled to aboutus section, active will be removed from main and added to aboutus section.

I tried using this to detect and add animation when active exist in aboutus section.

```
if($("section.aboutus").hasClass('active')) {
    $(".aboutus-text").addClass("animated fadeIn");
};
```

It is not working. I tried to see if addClass is working properly by removing the if statement, 'animated fadeIn' is added to aboutus-text.

Anyone can tell me how do I do this? Because I only want the animation to start when aboutus is active.

Comment: looks like your code is executed before the code that is adding the class is executed

Comment: add `console.log($("section.aboutus").attr('class'))` just before the `if` condition to see what are the classes present

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle of your code?

Comment: @ArunPJohny My console shows 'aboutus section'

Comment: @YoannM I am using this js call onepagescroll also.. so I have no idea how to customize jsfiddle to have it..

Comment: that means when your script is executed the `active` class is not added... the code that is adding the class is executed at a later time

Comment: @ArunPJohny Onepagescroll.js is also used in this along with bootstrap. So when i scroll to the next section (aboutus), I can see that the text exist there but just that there is no animation. I agree that it looks like the code was executed before.. Anyway I can work around this ?

Comment: @ArunPJohny what should I do to make this work? Should I hide the next section first and when active is present, I display it with the added animation?

Comment: @John is `Onepagescroll` a third party library, if so do you have a link to it

Comment: @ArunPJohny https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll . I wanted to use scrollTop to detect the height of this and let animation start only when scrolled to. But when I come to think of it, the height will always be changing on different screens.

Comment: but the plugin already has some animations isn't it... do you want your animations to run after that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62643/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-john).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin has an afterMove() callback, you need to use it

```
$(".main").onepage_scroll({
    easing: "ease",
    animationTime: 1000,
    afterMove: function () {
        if ($("section.aboutus").hasClass('active')) {
            $(".aboutus-text").addClass("animated fadeIn");
            $("section.aboutus").css({
                'display': 'block'
            });
        };
    }
});
```